# Pivot table giving wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

Below code gives me result set as shown in first image

```
  SELECT     dbo.tbStudent.Name, dbo.tbStudent.RegNo, dbo.tbFee.PID, dbo.tbFee.Purpose, dbo.tbFee.AmountPaid, dbo.tbFee.StudentID, dbo.tbFee.Date, dbo.tbFee.FeeID, 
                      dbo.tbFee.SemID, dbo.tbFee.CourseID, dbo.tbFee.ModeOfPayment, dbo.tbFee.CheckNo, dbo.tbFee.DDNo, dbo.tbFee.HostelDDNo, dbo.tbFee.FRID, 
                      dbo.tbStudent.Parentage, dbo.tbCourse.Name AS Course, ISNULL(dbo.tbSemester.SemName, ' + @st +') AS Semester
FROM         dbo.tbFee INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbStudent ON dbo.tbFee.StudentID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbCourse ON dbo.tbFee.CourseID = dbo.tbCourse.CourseID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSemester ON dbo.tbFee.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID  Where tbFee.SemID=1
```

[image: first image]

However using Pivot table I need result as below:

[image]

My code for pivot table is :

```
SET @values = '';
 If(@SemID=0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @values = @values +'['+ CAST(PurPose AS varchar(max))+ ']' + ','
        FROM tbFee Where CourseID=@CourseID
        SET @values = SUBSTRING(@values, 1, Len(@values) - 1)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @values = @values +'['+ CAST(PurPose AS varchar(max))+ ']' + ','
        FROM tbFee Where SemID=@SemID
        SET @values = SUBSTRING(@values, 1, Len(@values) - 1)
    END

 Declare @st nvarchar(max)
 set @st='''Not Available''';
 declare @q nvarchar(max)
set @q = '
 Select * from(

SELECT     dbo.tbStudent.Name, dbo.tbStudent.RegNo, dbo.tbFee.PID, dbo.tbFee.Purpose, dbo.tbFee.AmountPaid, dbo.tbFee.StudentID, dbo.tbFee.Date, dbo.tbFee.FeeID, 
                      dbo.tbFee.SemID, dbo.tbFee.CourseID, dbo.tbFee.ModeOfPayment, dbo.tbFee.CheckNo, dbo.tbFee.DDNo, dbo.tbFee.HostelDDNo, dbo.tbFee.FRID, 
                      dbo.tbStudent.Parentage, dbo.tbCourse.Name AS Course, ISNULL(dbo.tbSemester.SemName, ' + @st +') AS Semester
FROM         dbo.tbFee INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbStudent ON dbo.tbFee.StudentID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbCourse ON dbo.tbFee.CourseID = dbo.tbCourse.CourseID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSemester ON dbo.tbFee.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID  Where tbFee.SemID=1  
          ) as x
          pivot (
    max(AmountPaid)
    for Purpose in (' + @values + ')
) as pvt
'

exec (@q)
```

I am getting Values of Purpose columns in @values due to the reason that number of rows can change. However instead of getting result as single row for same student having same regNo , I am getting below result :

But what I am getting is below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the source query for your PIVOT, you should only specify those columns which are involved in the actual pivot - namely `dbo.tbStudent.Name, dbo.tbStudent.RegNo, dbo.tbFee.Purpose, dbo.tbFee.AmountPaid`.

```
SELECT     
dbo.tbStudent.Name, 
dbo.tbStudent.RegNo,
dbo.tbFee.Purpose, 
dbo.tbFee.AmountPaid
FROM         
dbo.tbFee 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbStudent ON dbo.tbFee.StudentID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbCourse ON dbo.tbFee.CourseID = dbo.tbCourse.CourseID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbSemester ON dbo.tbFee.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID  
Where tbFee.SemID=1
```

If any other columns apart from these are present, they will be factored into the pivot computation, and you will get multiple rows accordingly.

Comment: all these columns need to be present in result also, I just removed them in pics to make it readible. Source query is fine. It needs to be like this as I need all these columns.

Comment: The problem is that these other columns are causing your pivot result to be different from what you expect. You could do the pivot first and join pivot results to the other columns later.

Comment: That i understood, let me check